# Manager watches through CCTV

Tags: colleagues, ethics, privacy

I am currently outsourced to a agency. I work in place where they are tons of CCTV. For example, even now, behind my desk there's a CCTV to monitor. That is fine.

When I step out for a short breather or coffee break the terrace, my agency supervisor will immediately take a snapshot while viewing on the CCTV and send it to my company's HR and management. And a nasty email will go from agency supervisor to my company's HR and management saying I am missing. But in actual fact, I hold on to a duty mobile whereby I am contactable even if I am not at my desk.

I feel it's a violation of my privacy. Is it wrong to take short breaks? Or my agency supervisor is being nitpicky.

I have voiced out to my company's HR, and there's nothing much they can do as they want the contract so badly.

Comment: Outside of having your management tell the customer that you are entitled to stretch your legs from time to time and if he doesn't like it he can go to another agency, there is nothing that can be done to correct the customer. The other thing management  could do is promise you that they understand that he's being an ass and are ignoring his complaints; that wouldn't make your relationship with the customer any easier but it would at least make his actions mostly harmless (until he fires you and/or your firm in disgust). Nothing else is likely to be effective at addressing this.

Comment: Is there any reason he's picking on you in particular?

Comment: I guess you are not in Europe

Comment: @ed heal,No, based in asia for projects

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you know this is an issue, then stop walking away for breaks, take them at your desk, do some stretches in front of the camera etc,.

Because if you know it's an issue and yet you do it anyway, then you're asking for trouble and complaining just looks like whining. Most people at some time or other need to compromise and/or do things just to keep everything smooth..

Comment: I agree with this. If the company's culture does not allow for such leeway then there's not much you can do about it. The only other option would be to find a different job. Until that point, it would be in your best interests to keep your employers happy. While you may not agree with their policy, it's not something you can begin to change without being an employee with some significant influence in the company.

Comment: Also, if OP is based in europe, this is explicitly illegal with or without consent. You cannot film employees constantly unless safety requirements necessitate it